# Heroku migrate app to private space

Tags: heroku

Heroku introduced "private spaces", is it possible to migrate an existing app to a private space?
https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/9/10/heroku_private_spaces_private_paas_delivered_as_a_service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently not a one-click/command migration path (e.g. clone, fork), but apps in private spaces still use the same `cedar-14` stack, so most apps that work on Heroku today can be re-created in a private space and just work.